# I can't render a jinja2 template using a GQL query

Tags: google-app-engine

I am following a google app engine exercise and having trouble rendering a jinja template properly.

The following code does what I expect it to do (it allows me to render a template with values from my GQL query:

```
def get(self):
    blogpost = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM BlogPosts ORDER BY created ASC")
    self.render('blog.html',blogpost=blogpost)
```

That code renders my blog.html template with when I use tags like {{post.subject}}

This code does not let me render a template:

```
def get(self):
    path = self.request.path[1:]
    post = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM BlogPosts WHERE ID = " + str(path))
    self.render('permalink.html',post=post)
```

Comment: what does 'doesnt render my template' mean? do you get errors? are there no values in the template? did you try logging what path is? and  if you get an actual post or not?

Comment: @aschmid00 I don't get any errors. I get the html of my template with none of the {{templatevalues}} filled in with my query values. path is an int such as 1. I have tried using path as an int and casting it as a str to see if either would make my gql statement work. I don't see how I determine if my query results in an actual post. If you can tell me how to do that it would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe you can't query by ID this way. The id is part of the entity key so:

```
SELECT * FROM YourModel where __key__ = KEY('YourModel', <numeric_id>)
```

this should give you the desired result.

Comment: Or, avoid the query altogether and use `YourModel.get_by_id`. There's no reason to be doing a query here.